# What is the area of geom field?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to check the area of geometry values.

The geometry values are `POLYGON` or `POINT` or `MULTI POLYGON`.
The field has the type of `geometry`

I check the srid of the geom field:

```
select st_srid(geometry) 
from my_table
```

And I got srid=32636.

I checked here:
https://epsg.io/32636 and it seems that the units are in meters.

Now I want to get the area (in meters) of each value:

```
select st_area(geometry)
from my_table
```

And I'm getting very small values (0.0002, or 0.000097 or 0.33, ....).

I want to be sure:

- Does those values means square meter  (m^2) ?
- So the values are less than 1 square meter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your SRS unit is metre, [`ST_Area`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html) will return the area in square metres. The following example calculates the area of a polygon using SRS's that have different units:

```
WITH j (geom) AS (
  VALUES ('SRID=32636;
          POLYGON((-1883435.029648588 6673769.700215263,-1883415.1158478875 6673776.142528819,-1883411.8478185558 6673765.073005969,-1883431.7724919873 6673758.967942359,-1883435.029648588 6673769.700215263))'::GEOMETRY)) 
SELECT 
  ST_Area(geom) AS sqm,
  ST_Area(
    ST_Transform(geom,2249)) AS sqft 
FROM j;

        sqm        |       sqft        
-------------------+-------------------
 237.6060612927441 | 2341.135411173445
```

- EPSG 32636: Units are metres (Ellipsoid WGS84)
- EPSG 2249: Units are feet (Ellipsoid GRS1980)

To your questions:

> Does those values means square meter (m^2) ?

Yes.

> So the values are less than 1 square meter ?

Yes. I'm curious about what are your geometries about. Perhaps you mixed up different SRS?

**Unrelated note**: Spatial operations with SRS's that have the same unit might still deliver different results, as they might also use different [`ellipsoids`](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Ellipsoid). The example below will calculate the area of the same geometry using SRS's that have metre as unit but a different ellipsoid. Note the difference in the result:

```
WITH j (geom) AS (
  VALUES ('SRID=32636;
          POLYGON((-1883435.029648588 6673769.700215263,-1883415.1158478875 6673776.142528819,-1883411.8478185558 6673765.073005969,-1883431.7724919873 6673758.967942359,-1883435.029648588 6673769.700215263))'::GEOMETRY)) 
SELECT 
  ST_Area(geom) AS sqm_32636,
  ST_Area(
    ST_Transform(geom,26986)) AS sqm_26986
FROM j;


     sqm_32636     |     sqm_26986      
-------------------+--------------------
 237.6060612927441 | 217.49946674261872
```

- EPSG 32636: Units are metres (Ellipsoid WGS84)
- EPSG 26986: Units are metres (Ellipsoid GRS1980)

.. but if you stick to the same ellipsoid and unit, the math makes more sense:

```
WITH j (geom) AS (
  VALUES ('SRID=32636;
          POLYGON((-1883435.029648588 6673769.700215263,-1883415.1158478875 6673776.142528819,-1883411.8478185558 6673765.073005969,-1883431.7724919873 6673758.967942359,-1883435.029648588 6673769.700215263))'::GEOMETRY)) 
SELECT 
  ST_Area(
    ST_Transform(geom,2249)) AS sqft_2249,
  ST_Area(
    ST_Transform(geom,2249)) * 0.3048 ^ 2 AS sqm_2249, -- manually converted from sqm to sqft
  ST_Area(
    ST_Transform(geom,26986)) AS sqm_26986
FROM j;

     sqft_2249     |      sqm_2249      |     sqm_26986      
-------------------+--------------------+--------------------
 2341.135411173445 | 217.49859674966302 | 217.49946674261872
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=08d4ae57af2e1003c6b9b9c077880a5b)